# Parallel counting - Java

Tags: java, loops, memory, parallel-processing, hardware

I do not have a background in CS. I am really new to parallel programming and I do not know how exactly the hardware works when running a program. However, I have noticed the following. Say I have:

```java
public class Counter {
    
    private static int parallelCount = 0;
    private static int sequentialCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int n = 1000;
        
        // I count in parallel:
        IntStream.range(0, n).parallel().forEach(i -> {
            parallelCount++;
        });
        
        // I count sequentially:
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sequentialCount++;
        }
        
        System.out.println("parallelCount   = " + parallelCount);
        System.out.println("sequentialCount = " + sequentialCount);

    }

}
```

why I may get:

```
parallelCount   = 984
sequentialCount = 1000
```

I guess this has to do with the hardware and the way the compiler access memory. I am really interested to know why this happens. And what is one possible solution?

Comment: That's very unlikely as I am getting 1000 printed everytime I run the program. Make the variables as static and try again. One thing to note is the parallel behavior in streams is abstracted from the user and it makes use of the processor cores to achieve parallelism by executing the stream of data parallelly by splitting them into multiple smaller chunks.

Comment: Try to increase n, say to 100000. Are you still getting the expected result? I have also tried with static variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever more than one threads can access a value that is mutable then the system goes out of sync meaning the kind of problem that you are facing. No one can be sure what the result will be, and many a times the result will be wrong. You cannot guarantee which thread will write the value last.

Therefore, you need to `synchronize` the access to the shared resource (the integer you are incrementing) so that all threads get the latest updated value and the answer is always correct.

Coming to your program you can try making the `parallelCount` variable an Atomic Integer like `AtomicInteger parallelCount = new AtomicInteger();` An Atomic Integer is thread safe meaning that they can be concurrently updated without running the system out of sync.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Counter {

    private static AtomicInteger parallelCount = new AtomicInteger();
    private static int sequentialCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = 1000;

        // I count in parallel:
        IntStream.range(0, n).parallel().forEach(i -> {
            parallelCount.getAndIncrement();
        });

        // I count sequentially:
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sequentialCount++;
        }

        System.out.println("parallelCount   = " + parallelCount);
        System.out.println("sequentialCount = " + sequentialCount);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And what happens if I need, say, not an integer but a double sum? I have seen no AtomicDouble class exists.

Comment: Double and Long are not atomic in Java. I would suggest that you read about ```synchronized```, ```volatile```.

Answer (score 1):

- As you can expect standard for loop will increment sequentialCount 1000 times
- Regarding parallel stream, the application will try to open multiple threads which need to execute your function on parallel. In this situation, multiple threads can increment value at the same time and store value to int.

For example, suppose that we have two threads that working parallel and want to increment value from variable `parallelCount`. If `parallelCount` contains value 50. Both threads will read value 50 and calculate the new value 51 and store it to memory.

This approach can produce other concurrent problems. In order to solve this problem, you can use synchronization, locking, atomic classes, or another approach.

Answer (score 1):

## `AtomicInteger`

We can make use of [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) class from Java concurrency package while working with parallel streams as the behavior can be unpredictable while using primitive data type

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
public class Main
{
    private static AtomicInteger parallelCount = new AtomicInteger();
    private static int sequentialCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        int n = 100000;
        
        // I count in parallel:
        IntStream.range(0, n).parallel().forEach(i -> {
            parallelCount.incrementAndGet();
        });
        
        // I count sequentially:
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sequentialCount++;
        }
        
        System.out.println("parallelCount   = " + parallelCount);
        System.out.println("sequentialCount = " + sequentialCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple theads do an operation that is not atomic (incrementing a value).
The code you wrote translates to byte code and might cause something like this:

[image]

To avoid this, you need to synchronize the access to that critical code.
But note, that if all of your code is critical code, then it's redundant to use multiple threads.